# jquery bind blur & each

Tags: jquery, validation, bind, each, blur

i wrote this for checking data validation on page load:

```
$("input[min] , input[max]").each(function () {
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) < parseInt($(this).attr("min")) || parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(this).attr("max"))) $(this).addClass("invalid");
    else $(this).removeClass("invalid");
});
```

and then for user input validation i wrote this :

```
$("input[min] , input[max]").blur(function () {
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) < parseInt($(this).attr("min")) || parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(this).attr("max"))) $(this).addClass("invalid");
    else $(this).removeClass("invalid");
});
```

is there a way to bind them in one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger `blur` event after binding event. You don't need `.each()`

Use

```
$("input[min] , input[max]").blur(function () {
    if(parseInt($(this).val()) < parseInt($(this).attr("min")) || parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(this).attr("max"))) {
        $(this).addClass("invalid");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("invalid");
    }
}).blur(); //Here You can also use .trigger('blur')
```

Improvement, You can use [**.toggleClass( className, switch )**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-switch)

```
$("input[min] , input[max]").blur(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("invalid", parseInt($(this).val()) < parseInt($(this).attr("min")) || parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(this).attr("max")));
}).blur();
```

Comment: ok. it's work. thanks. but what difference between .blur() & .trigger('blur')?

Comment: @user3801352, Both are ways to trigger event handler programmatically